# How do I look for a text fragment within a file name?

Tags: python, text, operating-system, glob

I am reading data from an Excel file and then I am trying to find the file with the dir. The issue here is that I am missing a function.

For instance the Data could read `1011754723` but the text file would read `Hamlet1011754723_Page100.txt.` 
I found the function `.endwith(."txt")` but I couldn't find one with contains. Is there a function like this?

Thanks

Comment: You use `in`....

Comment: Use the Python keyword `in`.  `"1011754723" in "Hamlet1011754723_Page100.txt"` will return `True`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your issue? An error snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Well I was thinking more about in a folder if that makes sense. There isn't much of an error possible cause I don't know the function but the issue with glob is that I do not get a true. So what I have tried is: `for name in glob.glob(r"dir\*1011754723 .*"):
    print(name)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in`

With something like this:

```
'1011754723' in 'Hamlet1011754723_Page100.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my answer:

`for txt in glob.glob("dir/*1011754723*.txt"):
      txt_agg.append(txt)`